# solidity get function signature hash

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

are there any differences in gas, security between inline assembly and solidity methods to get function signature hash?

I want to know the differences between:

```
function getFunctionSigHash(bytes memory data) public returns(bytes4 funcHash) {
    bytes4 funcHash = bytes4(data);
}
```

and

```
function getFunctionSigHash(bytes memory data) public returns(bytes4 funcHash)  {
    bytes4 funcHash;

    assembly {
        funcHash := mload(add(data, 0x20))
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: The difference is one is solidity and one is assembly. What explanation are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

assembly code uses less gas because it has fewer instructions to be executed.

with assembly code you can check if an address is a contract address or not. you cannot check this in solidity

with assembly code you have more control over the control. you can even mention with memory slots you want to use.

[read more on docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.14/assembly.html)